# Facebook permissions writing on another persons wall

Tags: android, eclipse

I have one question regarding facebook permissions.

I have developed an app with facebook. When I use my fb account, it's no problem, when I use other's fb account, login is okay, but I want it to write on other's person wall, but it always shows `ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED`.

I don't know what's happening. Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: I can't help you with this, but you need to post your code and give a more detailed explanation of errors if anyone is to be able to help you with this. Also posting the contents of your LogCat will most likely be helpful.

Comment: Not sure why this has the `android` and `eclipse` tags at the moment.

Comment: I have copy this web page source code:http://javatechig.com/android/using-facebook-sdk-in-android-example